# Глагол соверш(е/ё)нного вида

Tags: грамотная-речь

Вроде бы глупый вопрос, но ответ не гуглится. Когда пишут о глаголах соверш(е/ё)нного и несоверш(е/ё)нного вида, вроде "делал-сделал", подразумевают Ё или Е?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**но ответ не гуглится**

В таких случаях можно смотреть ответ в словарях (в других случаях тоже лучше так делать). Например, [здесь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x) в "Орфографическом словаре". Вам нужен "совершенный вид", а не причастие (раз речь идёт о грамматической категории глагольного вида). Следовательно, пишется через "е".